# Mysql find common values for all users

Tags: mysql

We are developing an local shop reccomendation system and in one of our sql queries we had a problem
We want to fetch the companies which all users in same cluster rated , but if any one of the users in the same group doesnt rated the company we wouldnt want to fetch it

```
SELECT ml_user_clusters.primaryUser,ml_user_clusters.clusterId,ml_ratings.companyId,ml_ratings.rating,ml_user_labels.groupId FROM ml_user_clusters 
LEFT JOIN ml_ratings ON  ml_ratings.userId = ml_user_clusters.primaryUser
LEFT JOIN ml_company_user_labels ON ml_company_user_labels.companyId = ml_ratings.companyId 
LEFT JOIN ml_user_labels ON ml_user_labels.groupId = ml_company_user_labels.labelId 
WHERE ml_user_clusters.clusterId = 0
```

We've started to add a query like in the below but couldnt able to finish it with proper AND clause

And our data is like in the below: So in the result we would like to have only the companies which has groupId=6 because all users in the same cluster(clusterId=0) rated a company with groupId = 6

```
primaryUser clusterId   companyId   rating  groupId
497 0   135 5   NULL
498 0   135 10  NULL
79  0   135 12  NULL
501 0   135 10  NULL
79  0   85  14  2
79  0   8   4   5
79  0   98  11  5
79  0   3   5   5
497 0   6   7   6
500 0   6   7   6
499 0   29  7   6
497 0   29  7   6
499 0   77  7   6
500 0   29  7   6
498 0   6   7   6
500 0   77  11  6
500 0   130 3   6
498 0   130 3   6
501 0   77  19  6
499 0   6   7   6
79  0   30  1   7
500 0   30  7   7
79  0   48  7   9
79  0   39  1   13
79  0   48  7   13
499 0   6   7   15
497 0   6   7   15
79  0   8   4   15
500 0   6   7   15
79  0   98  11  15
498 0   6   7   15
79  0   3   5   15
79  0   81  7   15
79  0   3   5   17
79  0   82  7   17
79  0   103 7   17
79  0   118 3   17
79  0   63  3   17
501 0   118 7   17
79  0   82  7   19
79  0   118 3   19
79  0   63  3   19
501 0   118 7   19
79  0   39  1   21
79  0   85  14  23
```

**Expected output must be:** (Because all unique users in Cluster=0 has rated a company which has GroupID=6 )

```
primaryUser clusterId   companyId   rating  groupId

497 0   6   7   6
500 0   6   7   6
499 0   29  7   6
497 0   29  7   6
499 0   77  7   6
500 0   29  7   6
498 0   6   7   6
500 0   77  11  6
500 0   130 3   6
498 0   130 3   6
501 0   77  19  6
499 0   6   7   6
```

Do you have any idea how we can fix that problem?

Comment: Not my downvote, but it probably happened because you posted a fairly complex query without really explaining anything.

Comment: please give better explanation of expected output

Comment: Explain data model or setup fiddle session.

Comment: I've edited the data and also added the expected output

Comment: nosql db and map()/reduce() would be better suited for this task. At least it the query (Reduce function) would be much simpler

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work,you should build a fiddle for better testing.

Explanation: you count distinct users grouped by group id and compare with the total number of distinct users.If the two match it means all users in that respective groupid have voted.

```
SELECT ml_user_labels.groupId
FROM ml_user_clusters
LEFT JOIN ml_ratings ON ml_ratings.userId = ml_user_clusters.primaryUser
LEFT JOIN ml_company_user_labels ON ml_company_user_labels.companyId = ml_ratings.companyId
LEFT JOIN ml_user_labels ON ml_user_labels.groupId = ml_company_user_labels.labelId
WHERE ml_user_clusters.clusterId = 0
GROUP BY ml_user_labels.groupId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ml_user_clusters.primaryUser) =
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ml_user_clusters.primaryUser)
   FROM ml_user_clusters
   LEFT JOIN ml_ratings ON ml_ratings.userId = ml_user_clusters.primaryUser
   LEFT JOIN ml_company_user_labels ON ml_company_user_labels.companyId = ml_ratings.companyId
   LEFT JOIN ml_user_labels ON ml_user_labels.groupId = ml_company_user_labels.labelId
   WHERE ml_user_clusters.clusterId = 0)x
```